# What is the browser engine of the Sogou browser?

Tags: browser

Title pretty much says it all. I am developing for a client that serves a large customer base in China, so I need to make sure the site works in local Chinese browsers. I am experiencing issues with Sogou browser (which I'd never even heard about before today). In order to troubleshoot these issues in an environment I am more familiar with, I wanted to see if I could reproduce these issues in another browser which uses the same engine. If only I knew what engine that was…

Update:

As far as I've been able to find out, Sogou is a dual-engine browser. One engine is Webkit and the other supposedly is Trident, specifically the version that's in IE9. This however, does not correspond to what I am seeing, as the page is clearly rendered differently from what it is in IE9. Maybe it's IE9 in quirks mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen a [couple](http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Sogou%20Explorer) [references](https://code.google.com/p/sogou-explorer-bubble/) to a dual Trident/Webkit engine. Apparently it can do both; Trident might be either their own build, or the most recent version included with Windows. I have IE9 installed but it's behaving like IE7, which came default on my computer. Sogou-based browsers can be detected and offered to switch to the Webkit engine, like [in this code example](https://code.google.com/p/sogou-explorer-bubble/).

**From the Trident useragent string:**

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 7.0**; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; Media Center PC 6.0; SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0

Now I'm just guessing this means it uses [the IE7 standards mode as default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx) when it's rendering webpages. But then again IE doesn't like reporting the same useragent all the time either...

**From the Webkit useragent string (looks Sogou-branded):**

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.802.30 Safari/535.1 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0

I was able to change user agents pretty easily here. "高速" [translates roughly](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E9%AB%98%E9%80%9F) to "high speed".

[image: Sogou useragent switcher location]

Comment: This is insane...Sogu defaults to ie7 when it has webkit capabilities....why would anyone do that?  Anyway thanks for letting us know

Comment: What does the button that changes user agent say?

Comment: @CarlG Good question. Luckily I was able to find the answer in one of my own links. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how reliable the information is, but channel9.msdn.com has [a page](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/521915-China-Sogou-Browser-20-preview-release-fusion-Webkit-core-to-create-high-speed-browsing-experience) that suggest it is (or will be?) the Webkit engine.

Answer (score 0):

Chinese dual engine browsers have webkit and Trident. They use webkit by default and use Trident for compatibility mode. Apparently there were a lot of issues reguarding IE-centric websites. I think that has largely passed. For instance, Maxthon dropped the Trident engine in version 3+